# Drag and drop column data to another column

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, advanceddatagrid

In Flex, using AdvancedDataGrid, I'm trying to achieve a drag and drop of one row's column data to another row's column or the same row but different column.  Is this even possible?  I've been googling for hours and all I can find are drag and drop whole columns just to rearrange their view order.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to make columns draggable.

First is to make all the columns draggable in the DataGrid.  You can do this using the [draggableColumns](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DataGrid.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#draggableColumns) property on the DataGrid class.  Set its value to true.

The second is to set the [draggable](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridColumn.html#draggable) property on the DataGridColumn class.

In both cases, you would drag the columns using the column header.

If you want to be able to drag a single cell, there is no way to do this that I know of.